# Turn server relay ports are blocked in strict firewall

Tags: webrtc, coturn, rfc5766turnserver

I have established two turn server(Coturn) and a signaling server.
It works fine with normal networks.

```
Time    Component   Type    Foundation  Protocol    Address Port    Priority
0.012   rtp host    1178812653  udp 3f66affd-a34d-4622-8acc-5e50b4171bbe.local  64400   126 | 30 | 255
1.159   rtp relay   1762042148  udp 18.189.193.212  64237   1 | 30 | 255
1.159   Done
1.165
```

**when its come to strict firewall**

Turn server relay port range is blocked and treat as a threat in the firewall.

can anyone suggest how to solve this blocking?.

where to allow port range (client-side or turn server-side)?

new to webrtc any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if normal networks are working fine then it must be due to 'stun' servers that you might be using. Since you are saying u have 'coturn' server installed then u must verify if your 'coturn' server is working fine. use this link tp verify https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

3478 5349 these are the ports i guess used by coturn. u can allow them or which ever port u are using as:

```
sudo ufw allow 3478/udp
```

**port once verify i am not sure.

*** IT IS A SERVER SIDE ISSUE ***